# Not getting appointment subject using exchange service C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have Full Access for Room mailbox ("conf1@xyz.com"). So i can retrieve all meetings scheduled in Room. In retrieve appointments I'm getting Subject as organizer Name instead of appointment subject.

For Example:
**While Creating Appointment given data**

**Meeting Subject:** Test1

**Meeting Organizer:** Suneel@xyz.com

**Attendees:** x@xyz.com

**Location:** conf1@xyz.com

**While fetching data from Room getting subject as "Suneel" instead of "Test1"**

Can anyone help me on this?

```
CalendarView cView1 = new CalendarView(fromDate, toDate);

FolderId foldertest = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("conf1@xyz.com"));

FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = 
service.FindAppointments(foldertest, cView1);

findResults.Items.ToList().ForEach(d =>
{
    Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, new  
    ItemId(d.Id.UniqueId));
    roomAppointments.Add(appointment);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your seeing is normal depending on the configuration of the Meeting room eg for privacy reasons you don't want the subject of every Meeting visible to all users that have access to the Meeting room. You can change this configuration using Set-CalendarProcessing https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046(v=exchg.160).aspx and use the -AddOrganizerToSubject switch

Comment: I'm seeing organizer name instead of Subject... I have full access for that conference room.

Comment: The default setting is True so you should use -AddOrganizerToSubject $false to disable it. if you read the documentation "The AddOrganizerToSubject parameter specifies whether the meeting organizer's name is used as the subject of the meeting request. Valid input for this parameter is $true or $false. The default value is $true."

Comment: I did this... but still i m facing seeing Organizer as Subject. Any other way?

Comment: It won't change the existing data that change will only affect new appointments created after the change. The existing data wont changed as the subject property itself has been modified so the only way to change existing data is to modify the subjects back yourself.